# How to send data to a server using Post method and without using BLOB data type

Tags: java, sybase, ole, powerbuilder

#### Please consider the below information:

- I am working in Powerbuilder technology.
- An OLE web browser object is defined in a window of the Powerbuilder.
- Expected scenerio: Data from the Powerbuilder window will be passed to the server where the data will be parsed and a report will be generated which will be viewed in the OLE object in the powerbuilder window.

#### Steps taken:

- While sending data from the Powerbuilder window to the server, I do not want to append the data in the URL and send it to the Server. Therefore, I cannot use the Get method and so have tried with Post method.
- Used powerbuilder's PostURL method to send the data to the server.
- Below is an example:

```
    Int li_return
    String ls_url1, ls_url2
    Blob lb_blob
    Long ll_bloblen

    n_internetresult lu_data

    If GetContextService("Internet", iinet_base) = 1 Then
    ls_url1 = "http:// ip-address-of-the-server:port no./xxx?"
    ls_url2 = "here the data, that will be passed to the server, are stored"
    //*the data are converted into blob data*
    lb_blob = blob(ls_url2)
    ll_bloblen = len(lb_blob)
    ls_header = "Content-Type: " + "application/x-www-form-urlencoded~nContent-Length: " + string(ll_bloblen) + "~n~n"
    li_return = iinet_base.PostURL(ls_url1, lb_blob, ls_header, 8080, lu_data)
    End if
```

The above code is working fine. We can send data to the server successfully.

#### Problem

- The data is converted to Blob and sent to the server. In the server side, its getting difficult to convert the blob data to the data that we were passing from the Powerbuilder window. In the server side, the language used is java.
- So is there any way to send the data via **post** method *without* converting the arguments to blob data type in powerbuilder?

Powerbuilder version used: PowerBuilder Classic 12.5

Comment: What language is that? Most certainly not Java.

Comment: This is PowerScript language

Comment: OK. So, is converting to a blob making your data in the accepted `x-www-form-urlencoded` format, which is `var1=value1&var2=value2` etc?

Comment: Let me try to answer. Initially, the data was in the format var1=value1&var2=value2. After converting it into blob, I do not know whether it is making the data in the accepted format or not.

Comment: So, what is the difficulty? What errors do you get? Does the data on the server side look different than it was on the client side?

Comment: From the client side, the data is type casted to Blob datatype. In the server side, it appears as blob data type. Problem is, we are finding it difficult to convert the Blob data type to the original string, like var1=value1&var2=value2

Comment: Then it is not sent as those values, and it contradicts the header you have sent. The data should be sent in plaintext, US-ASCII encoding. It should not be seen as blob on the other side but be read as a simple HTTP Request.

Comment: We have an inbuilt method in the PowerScript language. That is the PostURL method. One of its example is in the description section. The PostURL method allows us to pass the Blob data only and not the plaiun text. This is the reason I am stuck. I am not able to send the data in a plain text format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can also pass the encoding to use when converting a string into a blob. I would recommend that so that you know what you are receiving on java side. If you don't, the systems default encoding will be used.

The main difference between a string and a blob in Powerbuilder is the missing termination null at the end of the blob, so converting shouldn't be that hard. Just do

```
new String (myBlob,"encoding")
```

Where myBlob is the received blob as an array of Bytes and encoding is the encoding used on Powerbuilder side.

I have not tried this myself, but I think it should work.